# cant put buffer gotten from fgets into an character array in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // printf() displays the string inside quotation
    FILE * fPointer; 


    int bufferLength = 255;
   char buffer[255];

    char *name[255];
    double floatie[100];
    int number[100];
    int count = 0; 
    int index1 = 1;
     int index2 = 1;
    int index3 = 1;


    fPointer = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    while(fgets(buffer,bufferLength,fPointer)){
       if(count == 0){
         buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
     
         char each[4550] = strncpy(each,buffer,sizeof(buffer));;
    
         each[sizeof(buffer)] = '\0';
         name[index1] == each; 
         //name[index1] = strdup(buffer);
         index1++; 
         count++; 
      }
       else if(count ==1){
          floatie[index2] = atof(buffer);
          index2++;
          count++;
       }
      else if(count ==2){
         number[index3] = atoi(buffer);
         index3++;
        count = 0; 
      }
  
  }

   printf("%s",name);




       return 0; 

   }
```

this is the code, adding buffer into float and int array works but i just cant add it into a character array. The file im reading is of this type:

```
  Sirius
   -1.44
   9
  Canopus
  -0.62
  313
  Arcturus
  -0.05
  37
  Rigel Kentaurus
  -0.01
  4
```

i used count to see whether the buffer is pointing at a string,float or integer.after so right now im just printing the names to test. and it is returning the last name in the file which is rigel kentaurus for all indexes. Im not sure why this does not work

Comment: First thing to do: check if `fopen` fails. Then don't use `strncpy` it does not what you think it does. Also it's not necessary here, simply use `strcpy`.

Comment: `char each[4550] = strncpy(...);` just isn't valid.

Comment: `each[sizeof(buffer)] = '\0';` isn't likely to be right either, what if the length of the string in `buffer` is shorter than `sizeof(buffer)`?

Comment: printf("%s",name); should be printf("%s",name[whatever index]);

Comment: And `name[index1] == each;` is wrong for two reasons: First because you use `==` instead of `=`, secondly because you save a pointer to a variable whose life-time will end as soon as the body of the `if` ends, making the saved pointer invalid almost immediately.

Comment: Finally I think you need to take a few steps back, go back to a few beginners books or tutorials, and start over with the basics.